# Hide Parent product category link on archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Im building a WP e-commerce site with multiple categories & sub-categories. On the archive pages each product has the product category titel printed under the product titel. So one product has two categories - prints and photography. Prints is child to photography - I want to hide the parent titel from the archive pages, but only when its a parent. It also prints out a "," between them in the html that I would have to be removed.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Theme used is: [Atelier](https://themeforest.net/item/atelier-creative-multipurpose-ecommerce-theme/11118909)

[image]

PHP from content-product.php that displays the category title inside the posted_in element:

```
<div class="product-details">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php
        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
        echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product_id, ', ', '<span class="posted_in">', '</span>' ); 
    ?>
    <div class="product-desc">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post($product_description); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Need more details: URL of archive page, the theme used, the screenshot of the page

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan Updated the question. Site is local though.

Comment: Find the template file which serving this archive page. To find current template file check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page then check the source code of template file to identify how the categories are displaying then you have to alter that by overriding that template file in your child theme

Comment: Hi @gvgvgvijayan . Yes, I have no problem finding what template, and Im familiar with the need. I dont know PHP enough to write what I need or to use a hook to make the parent category link titel not visible.

Comment: If you know the template then please share the snippet of the category displaying part from the rendered template file.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan Added it know, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213906/discussion-between-gvgvgvijayan-and-user3344734).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce can list the child category products too under the parent category even the parent category is not checked in the admin end.

[image]

So my suggestion to avoid listing the parent category (Photography) in product single page just check only the child category (Prints) in the backend. WooCommerce handles the process of listing the child products under the parent category.

[image]

**Additional Information:**

You have to understand the flat vs hierarchical categories. My preference always goes to flat hierarchy because if you want to export your products and import in another e-commerce system it won't maintain the categorizing logic as in WordPress so if you're used flat categories you can avoid the issue of the new system while importing products consider only parent category.

For e.g:

In WooCommerce this is our hierarchical structure

```
cat-a
  --prod-a1
  --prod-a2
  --cat-b
      --Prod-b1
```

If we sync it to square up e-commerce means it will consider parent category only
so it will import like this

```
cat-a
  --prod-a1
  --prod-a2
  --Prod-b1
```

It will ignore the child categories that's why WooCommerce also prefers not to check the parent categories and just check the product's category only.

Comment: My god that was ridiculous simple. Great answer - thank you very much!